# Google app engine dispatch file not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to route urls to my Google app engine module with the following dispatch.xml file in the WEB-INF directory of the default module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dispatch-entries>
  <dispatch>
    <module>internal</module>
    <url>*purge*</url>
  </dispatch>
</dispatch-entries>
```

However if I access the URL http://my-app.appspot.com/purge, it says

> Error: Not Found
>  The requested URL /purge was not found on this
>   server.

and in the logs I am seeing the /purge call on the default module instead of the internal module. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you run update_dispatch? You can see the dispatch information on the appengine dashboard

Comment: I had some problems with my directory structure, but after fixing those, appcfg gave me a warning and then I was able to do update_dispatch. I have more details in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the issue I was having was 2-fold. First of all, I had some configuration files (cron.xml, dispatch.xml, etc.) in my non default module. It is apparently very important to ONLY have these files in the default module, but the appcfg.sh script will not warn you about this, which was throwing me off. In fact it said

> INFO: Successfully processed
>   .../default/WEB-INF/dispatch.xml

However, once I removed these extra files, then appcfg.sh gave me a warning

> 99% Skipping dispatch.xml - consider running "appcfg.sh
>   update_dispatch "

Then finally I ran update_dispatch on the default module and it worked.